# USERCONTROL SHOWN AFTER RESPONSE.WRITE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My asp.net page has a usercontrol that shows a buttonbar at the top.

In the page_load i call a number of functions (in VB.NET codebehind) that build a response.write.  It all works fine, exept the usercontrol is shown BELOW the objects that came from the response.write.

How should i rearrange the call of the response.write functions in order to get the usercontrol-bar be place at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have a `response.write` on `Page_Load` and wait to render in the middle of page, because the `Page_Load` is called first and before the render starts.

Change the `response.write` with a literal control that you place it on the correct page position, or with a string and make the render on the page aspx side.

Comment: Thanks Aristos and Ali Issa, you are both right, i'll implement this!

Answer (score 1):

The response.write will always come at top.

What you can do is adding a literal control wherever you want and put the text you write in the response.write inside the literal control text property.